# SQL Join (all from one table and one from another)

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to retrieve all fields from one table on [condition1] and combine one field from another table in the results on [condition2], but my joins are not too hot yet:

```
SELECT * FROM table1 WHERE myField=123
INNER JOIN table2
SELECT myField2 FROM table2
ON (table1.condition = table2.condition AND table1.condition2 = table2.condition2)
```

Assistance is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried moving the where condition after the join conditions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your syntax needs some adjusting.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.myField2
    FROM table1 t1
        INNER JOIN table2 t2
            ON t1.condition = t2.condition
                AND t1.condition2 = t2.condition2
    WHERE t1.myField = 123;
```

Comment: Joe, you're awesome, thank you. Selecting your answer because it was the first I tried and it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is

```
SELECT table1.*, table2.field1
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2
ON table1.condition = table2.condition 
   AND table1.condition2 = table2.condition2
WHERE myField=123
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.MyField2
FROM table1 t1
INNER JOIN table2
   ON t1.condition = t2.condition 
  AND t1.condition2 = t2.condition2
WHERE t1.myField=123
```

Problems.

- All the columns you want to display in the result from MUST be listed in the outer most select.
- You don't need multiple SELECT statements unless you're executing a `union` or a `sub query`
- You can only use a select within a sub query if you wrap it in () and alias it as. `Select field from table A inner join (Select * from table2) B on A.ID = B.ID`
- Where clause belongs after the FROM and joins and join criteria.

In General... SQL syntax order is:

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. JOIN ON
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. HAVING
7. ORDER BY

Answer (score -1):

Alternatively, you can put both the join conditions in the where clause and join to the second table like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
      ,t2.myField2
FROM table1 t1
    ,table2 t2
WHERE t1.condition = t2.condition
    AND t1.condition2 = t2.condition2
    AND myField = 123
```

Comment: @SeanLange  Thanks for sharing the blog article! I definitely agree with not using old school syntax, but as suggested in my response "Alternatively", this is just an alternative method to get what the user has requested. Having said that, the blog article that you provided also clearly mentions that not using old school syntax is "This is subjective, of course, but seems to be a consensus.". So, I don't really see a reason why this response is not useful, hence downvoted.